# Disabling smtp authentication for local mail on same domain

Tags: linux, email, authentication, smtp

I am very new to smtp and am looking for something to deal with the current situation:

I have several servers running really old software (music automation) and they all need to report in daily via email. Unfortunately, this software is only able to deal with unauthenticated smtp, so they can't use an smtp server that requires a password. Also, none of them are on static IPs so I can't whitelist them either.

This is what I would like to make happen...

Let say one of the servers will be emailing reports from server1@foo.com. The reports will go to reports@foo.com which will be an alias forwarding to my real email address.

The question is: Is there a way to make this happen? I need an smtp server that will allow outgoing emails without authentication but I don't want an open relay. Just something that will allow emails to accounts and aliases within the same domain, foo.com.

Does smtp have a setting for this? Does any software provide this functionality? I've been thinking about writing a program/script to solve this problem but I don't even know where to start. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

By the way, this will be running on a VPS from wiredtree.com.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a small SMTP daemon (one per server) and tell the music daemon that its SMTP server is "localhost".

The daemon would bind and only listen on 127.0.0.1, and then would send outbound emails to its smarthost using regular authentication:

```
MusicDaemon --> unauthenticated --> local SMTP daemon --> authenticated --> real SMTP
```

You can write such a daemon by yourself - [some Python required](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html) - or you can check out one of [several possibilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server).

## Update

If you can do anything on the SMTP server, why not open it and/or tell it to handle yourdomain.com domain? That way, the server would not require authentication *for the mails directed to that domain*, while continuing being a closed relay (i.e. requiring authentication) for the emails directed elsewhere.

You can add some kind of filtering to reject all unauthenticated inbound emails *except* those pertaining to the reports. It shouldn't be necessary, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great ideas. I would like to see if there's a way to do this from the "real" smtp server side. For example, intercepting SMTP requests and doing something that way. I can do anything I want to the SMTP server but, for various reasons, the music servers "in the field" are kind of off limits.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Iserni. After a bit of experimenting, I found that smtp mail doesn't require authentication for local mail (same domain addresses / aliases). And also the real problem was that the client software was getting 550 Access Denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1). After disabling "Require RFC-compliant HELO" all the emails started going through again.